# Laravel : Update input with empty value

Tags: php, laravel

I have generated an **API** using Laravel.

In my **controller** I have the following function for the update :

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $data = Link::find($id);
    $data->title = is_null($request->title) ? $data->title : $request->title;

    $data->save();    
}
```

What is basically does it that it verifies **if** the received input is null, it **returns** the default value, **else** it requests the new one.

The problem here is that when I update the input with an empty value such as 5 space characters, the input in the database doesn't receive the new value because it considers the **space as null**.

I have in mind maybe a solution like checking the number of characters in the received input. Like if the received string is **less than 1** instead of `is_null` then return the default value . **Is it right ?**

Comment: 'it considers the space as null'. That is not true, Laravel has a ConvertEmptyStringsToNull 
 middleware which removes the spaces.

Comment: @Daan I see. So how can receive spaces in this case.

Comment: You disable the middleware.

Comment: @Daan Only in that controller? What if I need it somewhere else?

Comment: The middleware has an `except` property, you can define which routes you want to have excluded.

Comment: @Daan I've found `->withoutMiddleware(['']);` . It will do the same ?

Comment: @Daan I tried `Route::put('/link/{id}',  [LinkController::class, 'update'])->withoutMiddleware(['TrimStrings']);` didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did is that I modified `TrimStrings.php` located in **Middleware** folder, and added the keys I wanted to exclude from that **Middleware** like the following :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings as Middleware;

class TrimStrings extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The names of the attributes that should not be trimmed.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
        'title',
        'description'
    ];
}
```

Like that those keys will not be using **TrimStrings** and therefore they can receive spaces as value.